# How to reverse the axis direction in the given plot and combine them?

Tags: plotting, plot-themes

I have these two plots

[image]

```
{ Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Blue, AxesLabel -> {"x", None}],  
Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green, AxesLabel -> {"y", None}]}
```

I want to have the green plot such that the variable $y$ increases from right to left. Then, combine these two plots to get a picture as below

[image]

Thanks in advance for any hints or comments.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
plots = {Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Blue,  AxesLabel -> {"x", None}], 
   Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green, AxesLabel -> {"y", None}]};

Show[plots[[1]], plots[[2]] /. Line[x_] :> Line[{-1, 1} # & /@ x], 
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{#, Abs@#} &@Range[-10, 10]], Automatic}, 
 ImagePadding -> 20, PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Text["y", Offset[{-10, 0}, {-10, 0}], Right]}]
```

[image]

Also

```
Show[plots[[1]], 
 MapAt[GeometricTransformation[#, ReflectionTransform[{-1, 0}]] &, plots[[2]], {1}],
 PlotRange -> All, 
 Ticks -> {Transpose[{#, Abs@#} &@Range[-10, 10]], Automatic},
 ImagePadding -> 20, 
 PlotRangeClipping -> False, 
 Epilog -> {Text["y", Offset[{-10, 0}, {-10, 0}], Right]}]
```

> same picture

Answer (score 6):

Set the  `ScalingFunctions -> {{-# &, -# &}, {# &, # &}}`.

```
Show[Plot[Sin[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Blue, 
  AxesLabel -> {"x", None}], 
 Plot[Cos[x], {x, 0, 10}, PlotStyle -> Green, 
  AxesLabel -> {"y", None}, 
  ScalingFunctions -> {{-# &, -# &}, {# &, # &}}], PlotRange -> All]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But I want to have the axis values for the green curve positive, i.e. from $0$ to $10$. @cvgmt